# How to Combine 2 Backend (PHP Laravel and Spring)

Tags: java, spring, laravel, web-services, polyglot

I am newbie for web programming, and I have 2 websites (still local/intranet).

1. built with PHP Laravel
2. built with Spring Boot

What i have searched is (Polyglot, Microservice, API, Webservice)

My Questions :

1. How to Combine PHP Laravel and Spring Boot in 1 web ?
2. Tutorial/reference for it ?

I have example like this :

1. below using PHP CI for retrieve from database to datatables :
   [image]
2. below using Java for Form submit :
   [image]

Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean by combine? Please provide examples and a clear question.

Comment: i have sample picture above.. http://example.com/data1 using php laravel and http://example.com/registration using java

Answer (score 0):

You could run them both separately and have them communicate over a message bus Making one of them your primary backend which consumes the other one or you could try making a third micro-service which communicates with your PHP backed and spring boot back-end and acts as a single point of contact with your front-end.